# Why do I see "Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in ...." when I run ant (on RHEL 6.6) even though the path is set

Tags: linux, rhel, environment-variables, java, path

I created a script in `/etc/profile.d` and named it `jdk_home.sh`.  The contents of `jdk_home.sh` are as follows :

```
#!/bin/sh
export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/javac | sed "s:/bin/javac::")
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

(I followed an answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730815/unable-to-locate-tools-jar) on Stack Overflow to set up $JAVA_HOME).

I then typed `source /etc/profile.d/jdk_home.sh`on the command line. After that, I typed `echo $JAVA_HOME` and it gave me the following output:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.131.x86_64
```

After I typed `echo $PATH` I got this output:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.131.x86_64/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.131.x86_64/bin:/bin:/bin:/bin:/bin:/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-0.b13.el6_8.x86_64/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121/bin:/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/root/bin:/bin:/usr/apache/apache-ant-1.9.9/bin:/bin:/bin:/bin:/bin:/bin:/bin
```

I then opened another terminal in a project folder I named `dal`. I put `build.xml` in that folder. My `build.xml` has the following contents:

```
 <project name="Hello World Project" default="info">
<target name="info">
<echo>Hello World - Welcome to Apache Ant!</echo>
</target>
</project>
```

I typed ant there on the command line:

```
[root@gksrv dal]# ant
```

This produced the following output:

```
Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-0.b13.el6_8.x86_64/lib/tools.jar
Buildfile: /root/Desktop/dal/build.xml

info:
     [echo] Hello World - Welcome to Apache Ant!

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Why am I seeing the `tools.jar` warning? Doesn't the path contain the required information?

Comment: You don't want to put a `#!/bin/sh` in scripts that are sourced from `/etc/profile.d`. This has the side effect of starting another shell, doing your export commands and then exiting once done which won't source anything into your shell. You just want to put actual commands in `/etc/profile.d `files. Look at the other files in that directory as references.

Comment: @slm:  Are you sure?  I believe that all `/etc/profile/*.sh` files are invoked by **`.`** (i.e., `source`) — and, in that context, a shebang is just a comment.  Unnecessary, yes;  harmful, no.

Comment: @a_sid: You should probably not do software development as root unless you really *really* need to. In general, you shouldn’t do ***anything*** as root except what you absolutely have to do as root.

Comment: @G-Man Thank you for your suggestion. Why should we not do anything as root?

Comment: Because it’s like using a chainsaw to make your sandwich and a flamethrower to make your tea — it makes it easy for the slightest error to cause massive damage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I later discovered that `tools.jar` wasn't in the `jdk` directory. I ran the command `yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel`and `lib/tools.jar`became available in the java folder. 
When I ran the `ant` command after this, I did not get the same warning.

Comment: For future reference on yum-based systems whenever you run into a "I need to know what to install to get this file" problem you can use `yum whatprovides <path-to-file>` for instance, in this case: `yum whatprovides */tools.jar` Which lists all the packages that provide that file. That's usually a good one to start with.

Comment: @Bratchley: I believe the OP’s problem was that he thought that he had the file, but the system just wasn’t looking in the right place.  However, a more pertinent comment might be, “For future reference, whenever you get an `Unable to locate «file»` message, you should verify that you *have* the file, and determine where it is.”

Comment: @G-Man I don't think the OP implies they thought anything other than it should be in `$PATH` somewhere. In that case just trying to install a JRE-appropriate package that contains the file and retrying the operation is a valid troubleshooting MO.

Comment: For ubuntu users check if you install openjdk or openjdk-headless , if you install headless tools.jar is not installed